# Redirect in htaccess using replace and a wildcard?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need to create a redirect **to the same domain** in my htaccess like this:

`http://www.example.com/fr/checkout/N/review` Where **N** is a wildcard which  can take any number value.

to

`http://www.example.com/en/checkout/N/review`

Example:

`http://www.example.com/fr/checkout/65/review`

to

`http://www.example.com/en/checkout/65/review`

You can see that `fr` was replaced by `en` and the value of N was just inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch ^/fr/checkout/([^/]+)/review$ /en/checkout/$1/review
```

Comment: `RedirectMatch ^/fr/(checkout/\d+/review)$ /en/$1`